# How do I make a switch on the Arduino?

Tags: arduino, switches

I have the Freetronics Eleven, which is 100% compatible with Arduino Uno. Ultimately, I want to make a foot pedal switch that connects to a digital pin on the arduino so that a LOW is read when the pedal is pressed, and a HIGH is read when the pedal is released, or vice versa.

At the moment I'm just trying to test making a switch of the same behavior by sticking wires in the pins and connecting them together. I've tried connecting and disconnecting pin 2 and gnd, pin 2 and 5v, pin 2 and pin 12 etc. with pin 2 set to input.

What is the correct setup to make a basic switch? Which pin do I connect to which to make it so when the pins are connected one reads low instead of high, or vice versa?

EDIT: Thanks for telling me about the pull-up resistor. I have since discovered via google that the arduino pins have built-in pull-up resistors. For others who come along this problem, this is how you enable them:

```
pinMode(10, INPUT); // set pin 10 for input
digitalWrite(10, HIGH); // set pull-up resistor on pin 10
```

then to use:

```
if (digitalRead(10) == LOW) // pin 10 is connected to gnd
    doSomething();
else // pin 10 is not connected to gnd
    doSomethingElse();
```

Comment: I would say that a switch for Arduino is not different from a switch for anything else.

Comment: http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Switch http://www.ladyada.net/learn/arduino/lesson5.html

Comment: The internal pull-ups are very weak.  There is a good deal more that probably ought to be done, especially if you're connecting this footswitch on a long wire.  A capacitor to slow the transition a bit, an inline resistor or buffer to protect the Arduino, and debouncing the switch in software are all things you should look into.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need is a [pull-up resistor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pull-up_resistor).

[image]

The Arduino whebsite has a nice tutorial (with software) on using a [pushbutton](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Pushbutton).

> We connect three wires to the Arduino board. The first goes from one
>   leg of the pushbutton through a pull-up resistor (here 2.2 KOhms) to
>   the 5 volt supply. The second goes from the corresponding leg of the
>   pushbutton to ground. The third connects to a digital i/o pin (here
>   pin 7) which reads the button's state.

[image]

Comment: Beat me to the punch, I was typing an answer as yours popped up :)

@Nicholas Grasevski, Another way to visualize this with a [schematic](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5a/Pullup_Resistor.png).  2k2Ohm is a little stiff but will work just fine  .I usually prefer 4k7-10kOhm depending on what I have on hand.